# Joining to a date dimension with not yet specified dates

Tags: sql, date, ssas, cube, dimensions

I am building a multidimensional cube in SSAS.

One of my fact tables has a statusdateid which could be null (the required rules for this date have not been met yet so there is no status date). However this column still needs to be linked to the date dimension but with the null values in the table the cube wont process as the join fails

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there is a row that handles unknown dates in the date dimension such as a row with the date id -9 and all the related columns are unknown or 0